# very basic 2.5d rope physics

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I want to make a 2.5d grappling rope that lets the player swing around objects for quicker turning, but the code that I wrote doesn't work. The player just stops all velocity after a short amount of time.

````
       public Transform player;
       private float tikTok;
       public LayerMask layerMask;
       Vector3 tetherPoint;
       Transform tetherObject;
       Vector3 currentTether;
       float tetherLength;
       bool isTethered;
       Vector3 previousPlayerPosition;
       if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && Time.time >= tikTok && !isTethered) {
// this part works fine and dandy
            Ray ray = new Ray(player.position, player.forward);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit, float.MaxValue, layerMask)) {
                tetherPoint = hit.point;
                tetherObject = hit.transform;
                currentTether = tetherObject.position;
                tetherLength = Vector3.Distance(player.position, tetherPoint);
                isTethered = true;
            }
        } else if (isTethered && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) {
// this part does not
            if (Vector3.Distance(player.position, tetherPoint) > tetherLength) {
                player.position -= (Vector3.Distance(player.position, tetherPoint) - tetherLength) * (player.position - tetherPoint).normalized;
                print((player.position - previousPlayerPosition).normalized);
                player.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = player.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude * (player.position - previousPlayerPosition).normalized;
            }
        } else if (isTethered && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) {
            isTethered = false;
            tetherPoint = Vector3.zero;
            tetherObject = null;
            currentTether = Vector3.zero;
            tetherLength = 0;
        }
        if (tetherObject != null) {
            if (currentTether != tetherObject.position) {
                tetherPoint += currentTether - tetherObject.position;
                currentTether = tetherObject.position;
            }
        }
        previousPlayerPosition = player.position;```
````

Comment: How are you stopping code from exiting program?  You program is probably just ending.  Try adding to end of code Console.ReadLine() to stop program from exiting.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that it was in Update().

Comment: I mean FixedUpdate().

Comment: The best way of fixing is to put break point at end of section not working and then hover over each variable and writing value on a piece of paper.  Without knowing the values of each variable I cannot help.

Comment: This is unity. It has some extra functions that base c# doesn't have. The only value that is set in stone is layerMask, which is set to everything. Every other variable is defined by my code. I don't know what you want from me.

Comment: I really want you to solve the issue.   The problem is basic math algorithm which is hard to fix without running code with actual data.  Maybe best way of debugging is to output debug data to a file.  Then look at the file.  I would write data in CSV format and use string.Join("," new string[] {tetherPoint.X, tetherPoint.Y, tetherPoint.Z,currentTether.X, currentTether.Y, currentTether.Z, , tetherLength, isTethered? "true" : "false"})